# ASP.NET Core app for Raspberry Pi using Docker in VS2017

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, raspberry-pi

I want to deploy my Asp.Net Core 2.1 app to my Raspberry Pi 3.

Here is the scenario:
I developed the application in VS 2017 as a docker wrapped app

[image]

Raspberry Pi is running Raspbian with docker installed. 
The application is running fine on development machine, but when I deploy the image to Raspberry and try to run it there I'm getting the error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

I assume that this is happening because my image has wrong architecture (intel instead of arm), but I don't know how to fix that. Please advise.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication4/WebApplication4.csproj", "WebApplication4/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication4/WebApplication4.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication4"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication4.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication4.csproj" -c Release -o /app 

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication4.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
# This Dockerfile uses nightly preview builds for .NET Core
# It will be updated to .NET Core 2.2 shortly
FROM microsoft/dotnet-nightly:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY aspnetapp/*.csproj ./aspnetapp/
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY aspnetapp/. ./aspnetapp/
WORKDIR /app/aspnetapp
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


FROM microsoft/dotnet-nightly:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/aspnetapp/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

This is suggested at the official [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/). There are also some images tagged with arm32.

Comment: Probably I'm doing something wrong, but using nightly builds didn't make any difference. I've also tried arm images, but I'm not able to build an image on my windows machine.

Comment: @AlexK Did you try building the arm image on the pie itself?